# Get scale and precision of a NUMBER column through Java API?

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g, ojdbc

I have a question about Oracle DB. Suppose I have a column of NUMBER type. How can I get the precision and scale of this column through Java API?

Thanks so much.

Comment: you can refer this http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/Getcolumnsprecisionandscalevalue.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you already have a `ResultSet`, you can get its metadata which should provide the needed data:

```
int column = ...  // first column is 1 !!
ResultSet rset = ...

ResultSetMetaData metadata = rset.getMetaData();
int precision = metadata.getPrecision(column);
int scale = metadata.getScale(column);
```

If you don't have a `ResultSet`, just execute a SQL statement returning no rows as:

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(...);
Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT TheColumn FROM TheTable WHERE 1 = 0");
                             // or "SELECT * FROM TheTable WHERE 1 = 0");
```

More details of what the metadata offers: [ResultSetMetaData](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html)

Comment: Thanks. So that means I cannot get the precision or scale of the column if the a table it belongs to is empty?

Comment: sure you can - "execute a SQL statement returning **no rows**", despite you **can** also execute a statement returning some or all rows [:-).

Answer (score 2):

You even do not need to create a query. You can use DataBaseMetaData. And then find out all about your Database. (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html)

```
DataBaseMetaData dmd = connection.getMetaData();
ResultSet rs = dmd.getColumns("DB-Name", "Schema-Name","TableName","ColumnName");
System.out.println("Type Name: " + rs.getString(6) + "\n" +
"Column Size: " + rs.getInt(7) + "\n" +
"Decimal Digits: " + rs.getInt(9) + "\n" +
"Radix: " +  rs.getInt(10) + "\n" );
```

There is a lot of Information you can collect by DataBaseMeta. It is very well documented on the Java-API-Docs. 
Be aware it might consume a lot of resources, when you are scanning huge databases.